# modular forms of half-integral weight: order, fourier series.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, modular-forms

Let $f$ be a meromorphic modular form of weight $r/2$ with $ r\in \mathbb{Z}$ for congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ and multiplicator system $v$. $f$ now has a period $N = lR$, where $R$ is the smallest translation 
\begin{equation}
T^R = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & R \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma \quad \text{and}
\end{equation}
$l$ is the order of the roots of unity in $v$. Then there exists the usual fourier series
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{n= \infty}^{\infty} a_n e^{2\pi i n z / N }.
\end{equation}
But if we view at the value of $v$ for the translation  $v(T^R) = e^{2 \pi i \nu / l }$, we can write the fourier series as
\begin{equation}
f(z)  e^{2 \pi i \nu / l } = \sum_{n= \infty}^{\infty} b_n e^{2\pi i n z / R}
\end{equation}
with $b_n := a_{\nu + l n }$. We now define the order of $f$ in $i \infty$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{ord}(f; i \infty) = min \{ n; b_n \neq 0\}.
\end{equation}
My question ist: Why don't we just define the order of $f$ as  $\{ n; a_n \neq 0\}$?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If $f(z)$ is meromorphic on $\Im(z) > 0$ and $2\pi T$ periodic then $F(q) = f(\frac{T \log q}{2i \pi})$ is meromorphic on $0 < |q| < 1$. If $F$ is also meromorphic at $q=0$ then you can define the order $N$ of its pole at $q=0$, write its Laurent series $\sum_{n=-N}^\infty c_n q^n$ and obtain $f(z) = \sum_{n=-N}^\infty c_n e^{2i \pi n z/T}$ valid for  $\Im(z)$ large enough.

Comment: Yeah right that is be way I know the order $N$ of a pole. But I found the definition above in some literature which confused me, because I don't see any advantage?

Comment: I meant $f$ is $T$-periodic. As you see $F(q)$ has a Laurent series on $0< |q| < r_1$ but also other Laurent series on $r_i < |q| < r_{i+1}$, and $f(z)$ has different Fourier series on horizontal strips (with poles on the boundary). There is not much more to say, except that if $f(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})$ is meromorphic at $i\infty$ for every $ab-cd=1$ and is weight $k/2$ invariant for $\Gamma$, then you can apply to $f(z)^2$ the theory of meromorphic functions on the compact Riemann surface $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$.